# bash: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, memory, ram, space

```
$ echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
bash: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied
```

Tried with the system password. But still failing.

Comment: `Tried with the system password` - how exactly did you try it?

Comment: The normal system password right ? @KamilCuk

Comment: What exactly did you typed? Where did you typed the "password"?

Comment: when I typed command
$ sync 
$  su

Comment: root@my:/var/log# echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
-bash: /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches: Permission denied

Answer (score 28):

Execute the shell as root:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'
```

Or redirect the input to a process that will write to file as root:

```
echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Answer (score 1):

There is another possibility (not mentioned in answers here yet) is when you use a OpenVZ server, where even the "root" user may not be able to change the proc values.

Mine had read only permissions for root, and even though group was root, I couldn't change it with chmod.

For more info, refer to answers here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109496/echo-3-proc-sys-vm-drop-caches-permission-denied-as-root

Answer (score 0):

You should do it with root user. Or atleast should use sudo then command.

```
sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```